# xPages dojox.grid.cells.Cell.formatEditing() (replace function)

Tags: replace, xpages

I want replace this function by:

```
formatEditing: function(inDatum, inRowIndex){
    this.needFormatNode(inDatum, inRowIndex);
    return '<input class="dojoxGridInput" type="text" value="' + inDatum.replace(/"/g, '&quot;') + '">';
},
```

How i can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dojox.grid.cells.Cell.prototype.formatEditing = function(){}